# Laravel API Passport : Get 1 parameter from Array : Auth::user()->token()

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api

I'm trying to get the `id` parameter from an array of `Auth::user()->token()`

Currently This is the response I have.

```
{
"status": "error",
"message": "Your Token is Expired!",
"token": {
    "id": "12d4da900352cf23be1ada7d54052e11dc383c267f2d98e799790a34dbfe64a5b732f0b7137d0586",
    "user_id": 1,
    "client_id": 2,
    "name": null,
    "scopes": [],
    "revoked": false,
    "created_at": "2019-05-15 04:22:04",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-15 04:22:04",
    "expires_at": "2019-05-16 04:22:04"
}
```

}

I just want to take out the `id` inside the `array` and I will use to query on the other side of my system as variable. Is it possible to take out this parameter from that array?

My code for that response in my postman.

```
$tokenArray = Auth::user()->token();
return response(['status'=>'error','message'=>'Your Token is Expired!','token'=>$tokenArray]);
```

I just put the `$tokenArray` in the `response` so that I can easily see if it is working. But I will remove it once I get the output that I want.

Comment: try `Auth::user()->token()->id`

Comment: if you other end uses javascript then you can try `console.log(response.token.id)` assuming response is what is returned

Comment: Hahaha how stupid I am. Thanks bro. It works. It shows "token": "12d4da900352cf23be1ada7d54052e11dc383c267f2d98e799790a34dbfe64a5b732f0b7137d0586"

Comment: Noted @Aditya Thakur for future situation purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
Auth::user()->token()->id
```

To get `id` directly